# How do I get Excel to automatically replicate functions across the spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, replication

I have a spreadsheet where I'm doing a whole table of calculations.  I'm playing with the calculations and seeing what it does to the data.  I expect to change the calculations dozens of times (at least) during this process.

When I change the calculation, I then have to highlight the cell, grab the handle, and drag it to the bottom of the column.  Then I have to highlight the column, grab the handle, and drag it all the way to the right of the spreadsheet.  This will then copy this updated calculation to all of the cells in the sheet.

How can I get this to happen automatically?  When I change the formula in the top left cell, I want this change to replicate to all of the other cells automatically.  Is this even possible?

Comment: If I update the top-left cell, I can select it and double click on the handle.  This copies the formula to all of the cells directly below, which seems like half the problem.  This is still a manual solution, though, and I would like an automatic one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of filling down then filling across you can copy the cell in the top-left corner, then select the entire range (Ctrl+Shift+End) and do Paste.

If you truly want something automated, you'll need to use VBA. This would be done with the Worksheet_Change event. Let me know if you want that solution.

Comment: That's easy enough that I can do it manually.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Select all the cells with the formula
2. Change the formula in the formula bar
3. Use the `ctrl-Enter` combination instead of Enter

The new formula will be replicated in all the cells, while still keeping them selected.